# Cannot connect to Minecraft servers after a router update

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My stepdad updated our comcast router, and since then I haven't been able to go on any multiplayer minecraft servers I play. It shows the loading bar and then says "cannot connect to server",

I then try to log in and when I do it doesn't work. I've tried alot of stuff and look for answers but all I can see is questions about people having issues hosting their own servers. So can some please help me fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your router is blocking the ports required to connect to a multiplayer server. It's impossible to provide more assistance without knowing the exact model of router you have, but essentially you will need to go to the router admin page and find the settings that are causing the problem.

Comment: Router updates will sometimes remove all customizations like Port forwarding.